# Raspberry Wifi looses connection when lan cable unplugged

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, lan

Using latest Buster release, I can set up my wifi and lan and it works fine. However, if I remove the lan cable, then there is no connectivity through the wifi. The Pi cannot even be pinged. I am using a dhcpcd.conf file that is the same as another Raspberry that works when the lan cable is unplugged. What am I missing?

This is the dhcpcd.conf file

```
# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# Most distributions have NTP support.
#option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate SLAAC address using the Hardware Address of the interface
#slaac hwaddr
# OR generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses based from the DUID
slaac private

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.22/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.18 8.8.8.8
static domain_search=

interface wlan0
inform 192.168.0.23
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.18 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this work but I don't understand why I had to do this. I changed the metric value for each and made the wifi a higher priority, (a lower number). That seems to make it work.